# Getting a list of all fields in a class using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am writing JNI code for a game and I'm trying to get all fields of a particular class. Here's my code. It crashes at line 5 where I call `CallObjectMethod`. `classes` is an unordered map mapping `std::string` to `jclass`.

```cpp
void getAllFields(std::string className) {
    jclass klass = getClass(className);
    if (klass == NULL) return;
    jmethodID getFields = env->GetMethodID(klass, "getFields", "()[Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;");
    jobjectArray fieldsList = (jobjectArray) env->CallObjectMethod(klass, getFields); // error on this line
    jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(fieldsList);
        
    for (jsize i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        jobject field = env->GetObjectArrayElement(fieldsList, i);
        jclass fieldClass = env->GetObjectClass(field);
        jmethodID getName = env->GetMethodID(fieldClass, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
        jstring fieldName = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(field, getName);
        const char *cFieldName = env->GetStringUTFChars(fieldName, 0);
            
        std::cout << cFieldName << std::endl;
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(fieldName, cFieldName);
    }
}
    
jclass getClass(std::string className) {
    if (classes.contains(className))
        return classes.at(className);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You are not checking to make sure `env->GetMethodID()` is successful before calling `env->CallObjectMethod()`. You need to check the return value of `GetMethodID()` for NULL

Comment: Unrelated: since all your array members are of type `java.lang.reflect.Field` you can just look up the class and its `getName` method once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grab the `getFields` method from the metaclass, not the class.

Change the line for `getFields` as follows:

```
jmethodID getFields = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(klass), "getFields", "()[Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;");
```

It is an error in JNI to call `GetMethodID` on the same object as you do `CallXXXMethod`.